# noun ends with *-ing* but not a gerund?

Tags: gerunds

> A gerund (often known as an -ing word) is a noun formed from a verb by adding -ing. ... **Not all words formed with -ing are gerunds.**

Is there an example of noun ends with *-ing* but it's not a gerund?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the comments, there are many words which end in "-ing" which are not gerunds -- "filling", "thing", "icing", etc.  If you're curious about the derivation of these words you can consult [an etymology dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=icing).  Some probably originally derived from the gerund of related verbs (like "frosting"), while others simply evolved into nouns from similar-sounding older words (like "swing").

Unfortunately, while there are patterns this may not be obvious to anyone but a language expert.  English a mix of several dissimilar languages and so any word can have a unique origin.

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ing

Answer (score 3):

Other short words ending in ing, that can't be gerunds of a verb: ring, king, sling, sting.

A word doesn't become a noun, adjective, gerund or any other part of speech until it is used in a sentence. So, ask not what a word "is", rather ask how it is used.

For example "I enjoy drawing cats" (a gerund). "I have a drawing of a cat" (noun)

The suffix -ing is used in modern English for both participles and gerunds, this is the result of errors and confusion by Anglo-norman scribes in the 12th century, converting the participle ending -ende, first to -ind then to -ing, so it matched the gerund.

Comment: We could also add these nouns to  your list: *wing, zing,* and *everything*.

Answer (score 1):

- <blessing> (a fortune)
- <drawing>/<painting> (an image)
- <working> (a detail)
- <wiring> (a structure)
- <matting> (a material)
- <funding> (a set of money)